# Rails root_url has two forward slashes when default_url_options trailing_slash is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller

When this line is set in the application.rb file:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { trailing_slash: true}
```

The `root_url` contains two forward slashes:

**www.example.com//**

Without that line we get:

**www.example.com**

The reason we have this is SEO purposes, the site was converted from php and we wanted to maintain consistency.

**Question:** Is there any way to remove the double forward slash? It only started doing this recently... maybe a recent change in Rails? (We always update to the latest.)

**Update:** Was able to reproduce with a default app. (Rails 3.2.8) https://github.com/silasj/rails_test_forward_slash

Gihub Issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8700

Comment: Will spin up a new rails app and see if I can reproduce then.

Comment: please open an issue on https://github.com/rails/rails/issues I'll take a look.

Comment: does it happen in 3.2.9?

Comment: Issue on github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8700d

My test is 3.2.8, our app is 3.2.9 (looks like it was updated recently w/out my knowledge), and it occurs on both.

Comment: @Silasj For me, without the trailing_slash declaration. I get www.example.com/  . and with the trailing_slash I get www.example.com//   (rails 3.2.9)

Comment: @Nishant I get the same as you with 3.2.8, but with our app, I am getting the results I stated in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rails bug. I tracked it down and submitted a PR to solve the problem https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8701

I think we can merge it in in the near future. I'll try to backport the patch to `3-2-stable` so that it will be available in the next `3.2.x` release.

EDIT: PR is merged into rails/master and rails/3-2-stable. Sadly a little to lait for 3.2.10, need to wait for the next release ;).